# Publishing snapshot data when subscriber connects to publisher in ZeroMQ PUB/SUB model

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system, low-latency

I have a simple ZeroMQ `PUB/SUB` architecture for streaming data from the publisher to subscribers. When the subscribers are connected, publisher starts streaming the data but I want to modify it, so that publisher publishes the most recent snapshot of the data first and after that starts streaming.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *How can I achieve **this**?*
>   <sub>( ***this*** being: "... streaming the data but I want to modify it, so that publisher publishes the most recent snapshot of the data first and after that starts streaming."</sub>

### Solution :

Instantiate a pair of **`PUB`**-s, the first called **`aSnapshotPUBLISHER`**, the second **`aStreamingPUBLISHER`**. Using **`XPUB`**-archetype for the former may help to easily integrate some add-on logic for subscriber-base management ( a NTH-feature, yet kinda O/T ATM ).

Get configured the former with `aSnapshotPUBLISHER.setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE, 1 )`, other settings may focus on reducing latency and ensuring all the needed resources are available for both the smooth streaming via `aStreamingPUBLISHER` while also having the most recent snapshot readily available in `aSnapshotPUBLISHER` for any newcomer.

`SUB`-side agents simply follow this approach, having setup a pair of working (`.bind()/.connect()`) links ( to either of the `PUB`-s or a pair of `XPUB`+`PUB` ) and having got confirmed the links are up and running smooth, stop sourcing the snapshots from `aSnapshotPUBLISHER` and remain consuming but the (now synced using BaseID / TimeStamp / FrameMarker or similarly aligned) streaming-data from `aStreamingPUBLISHER`.

The known `ZMQ_CONFLATE`-mode as-is limitation of not supporting multi-frame message payloads is needless to consider a trouble, once a low-latency rule-of-thumb is to pack/compress any data into right-sized BLOB-s rather than moving any sort of "decorated" but inefficient data-representation formats over the wire.